# MSMQ Access issue in NServiceBus with asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, msmq, nservicebus

I am trying to implement publisher - subscribe in my project of asp.net (wcf) web services. When i am trying to create bus in global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();                
            Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
          .SpringBuilder()
          .BinarySerializer()
          .MsmqTransport()              
              .IsTransactional(false)
              .PurgeOnStartup(false)
          .UnicastBus()
              .ImpersonateSender(false)
          .CreateBus()
          .Start();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
  public static IBus Bus { get; private set; }
```

but it is not creating bus.. then it is throwing exception

```
    Exception reached top level.
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Peek(TimeSpan timeout)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.Receive()
   at NServiceBus.Utils.WorkerThread.Loop()
```

**How Can I Avoid this?.... .... I am struck in the middle...**

nRk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a security issue, make sure to give everyone full rights to the queues involved

hope this helps!